# ¿Como llamar a una actividad desde un fragment? Android Studio + Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, app

Quiero llamar o abrir una actividad desde un fragment en mi aplicacion con kotlin, lo trate de llamar con setOnClickListener pero algo pasa con intent, porque no lo reconoce.
Normalmente para llamar a una actividad se usa:

```
        textView12.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this , miactvidad::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

Pero talvez la forma de llamar a una desde un fragment sea diferente
Este es el codigo que tengo:

```
package com.example.bottom.ui.notifications

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import com.example.bottom.R
import com.example.myapplication.olvidaste
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.olvidasteContraseña
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_notifications.*

class NotificationsFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var notificationsViewModel: NotificationsViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        notificationsViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NotificationsViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notifications, container, false)
        textView12.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this , olvidaste::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_notifications)
        notificationsViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            textView.text = it
        })
        return root
    }
}
```

Por cierto este es el error que recibo al tratar de ejecutar mi app:
e: C:\Users\brand\AndroidStudioProjects\bottom\app\src\main\java\com\example\bottom\ui\notifications\NotificationsFragment.kt: (27, 26): None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
public constructor Intent(p0: Context!, p1: Class<*>!) defined in android.content.Intent
public constructor Intent(p0: String!, p1: Uri!) defined in android.content.Intent

Gracias si pueden resolver mi problema

Comment: prueba con this@MiFragmentNameDondeEstaElTextview

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que startActivity es un método de Context, y para crear un Intent explicito también necesitas un Context.

La clase Fragment no hereda de Context, por lo que deberás obtener el Context llamando a requireContext()

```
textView12.setOnClickListener {
    requireContext().let{
        it.startActivity(Intent(it, olvidaste::class.java))
    }
}
```